# Cómo llamar un Public Void automáticamente al abrirse la app

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente `public void`:

```
public void GetIMEI(){
   String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IMEI: " + deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Y quiero que se ejecute automáticamente cuando se abre mi app en el dispositivo donde estará instalada. ¿Cómo logro dicho cometido?

Comment: Si lo llamas desde el onCreate de la `Activity` principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu método `onCreate()` que es el método que se llama para iniciar tu `activity` puedes agregar al final la llamada a tu método de la siguiente manera:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       GetIMEI();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya me lo habían contestado en stackoverflow en inglés. Pero la voy a dar como correcta por si otra persona ve este post en el futuro y tiene la misma duda, va a saber que esta es la forma correcta.